# Result by custom index from mongolab using rectangular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, restangular, mlab

I am trying to use a custom index in a MongoLab Collection, but I can't figure out how to get a Restangular.one response using this custom index. In truth, I can't even figure out how to send the call to MongoLab using just a URL with a custom index.

So, for instance, my collection has added the custom index "sitename". I tried this:

```
    .when('/sites/:sitename', {
      templateUrl: 'views/site.html',
      controller: 'SiteCtrl',
      resolve: {
        site: function(Restangular, $route){
          return Restangular.one('sites', $route.current.params.sitename).get();
        }
      }
    })
```

but that didn't work. (I wasn't surprised). I also tried adding 'sitename' to the setRestangularFields section:

```
  RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
    id: '_id.$oid'
  });
```

That also didn't help.

- Is there a way to do a Restangular.one with a custom index?
- Is there a any way to get a single document back from MongoLab using something other than _id?

thanks for any help,

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out with the help of Martin (maker of Restangular) and MongoLab support. Turns out I needed to do a customGet with Restangular and use the q: parameter to satisfy MongoLab. The final piece of code is a change on one line:

```
return Restangular.all('sites').customGET("", {q: { "sitename" : $route.current.params.sitename } });
```

so, the whole section would look like this:

```
.when('/sites/:sitename', {
  templateUrl: 'views/site.html',
  controller: 'SiteCtrl',
  resolve: {
    site: function(Restangular, $route){
      return Restangular.all('sites').customGET("", {q: { "sitename" : $route.current.params.sitename } });
    }
  }
})
```

Hope this helps you.

Scott